# Check if event (doubleClick) is running

Tags: c#, events

I am writing a tool which switchs between a lot of states. For some events I need to be sure they wont get executed a second time while the called function (inside the event) is running. This is how I managed it before:

```
// Global variables //
public bool func1IsRunning = false;
public bool func2IsRunning = false;
...

public void listView_DoubleClick(object sender, EventArgs e) 
{
    if(!func1IsRunning)
    {
        func1();
        func1IsRunning = false;
    }
}

public void func1()
{
    func1IsRunning = true;
    // some code in here //
}
```

But with every extension of my tool the list of the global variables grows up. Also the events and functions getting less clear to read.

Isnt there a way like this(?):

```
public void listView_DoubleClick(object sender, EventArgs e) 
{
    if(DoubleClick.IsHandled)
    {
        func1();
    }
}

public void func1()
{
    // some code in here //
    // ................. //

    DoubleClick.IsHandled = true; // at the end of the function //
}
```

So what I am looking for is a way to determine if an event is still running or not. My code is working, im just unhappy with how it looks like.

Any ideas?

---

**UPDATE 1**

I decided to use **Steve's** answer as it solves my problem by the clearest way.
Anyway it is **NOT** running correctly for now.

Here is how my code looks like:

```
public void listView_DoubleClick(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            try
            {
                listView.DoubleClick -= new EventHandler(listView_DoubleClick);
                itemEdit();
            }
            finally
            {
                listView.DoubleClick += new EventHandler(listView_DoubleClick);
            }
        }
```

The code above is NOT disabling the handler.

```
public void listView_DoubleClick(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            try
            {
                listView.DoubleClick -= listView_DoubleClick;
                itemEdit();
            }
            finally
            {
                listView.DoubleClick += listView_DoubleClick;
            }
        }
```

This code is also not disabling the handler.

This is the line where the handler gets enabled (MainForm.Designer.cs):

```
this.listView.DoubleClick += new System.EventHandler(this.listView_DoubleClick);
```

There are no errors raised. The event just gets fired again and again. Where is the problem?

**UPDATE 2:**
As Sinatr asked in the comments below if my function is really waiting or just enabling user input he discovered where the mistake was made.

Steve's answer is correct according to my wrong written question. Thanks a lot to all of you guys.

Comment: Problem is in the logic. Your `itemEdit()` can't rise `DoubleClick` event directly (well, maybe you use some mouse hook calls there, but it's unlikely). So why do you unsubscribe from `DoubleClick` before calling `itemEdit()`? Common mistake of posters is to post *solution* to some problem which *they think* is the way to solve problem. Then nice people here solve *solution*, but the problem still, because *solution* was wrong.  See [XY problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/66377).

Comment: Replace `new System.EventHandler(this.listView_DoubleClick)` with just `this.listView_DoubleClick`. To "unregister an event" you need to `-=` the EXACT delegate you `+=`'ed => `+= new ...` can not be unregistered as you do not have a reference to the exact delegate anywhere.

Comment: @ChrFin: Changed my code, but it is still firing up.

Comment: @Sinatr: What the hell? Why Im disabling the doubleClick before itemEdit()?. Easy: ItemEdit is waiting for user-input serval times. I dont want the user to fire the doubleClick-event in this time! So it HAS to be disabled before itemEdit starts running through. After itemEdit is done, it can be enabled again.

Comment: `itemEdit()` waiting for user-input several times? Are you sure it is *waiting*? Or, what I think is more true-ish, it simply *enables* user input, so all the story with flags or subscribing/unsubscribing doesn't makes sense at all.

Comment: Oh god I found the mistake...Even if u sound like being an as*****, thanks for this comment.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just disable the event handler

```
public void listView_DoubleClick(object sender, EventArgs e) 
{
    try
    {
         listView.DoubleClick -= listView_DoubleClick;

         // Now, even if func1 causes a DoubleClick event,
         // or user manages to trigger a DobuleClick
         // there is no event registered and this code could
         // reentered until you exit from func1.
         func1();
    }
    finally
    {
         // Important part. the finally block is required 
         // because you should readd the event handler 
         // ALSO in case an exception occurs in func1 
         // and it is not handled there
         listView.DoubleClick += listView_DoubleClick;
    }
}
```

**EDIT**

Looking at your comment I suspect that this DoubleClick event is assigned to more than one control. If this is the case, using the global `listView` global instance of a listview doesn't disable the double click on other controls that are linked to the same code.
If this is the case then you need a more generic approach

```
public void listView_DoubleClick(object sender, EventArgs e) 
{
    Control c = sender as Control;
    try
    {
         if(c != null)
         {
              c.DoubleClick -= listView_DoubleClick;

              // Now, even if func1 causes a DoubleClick event,
              // or user manages to trigger a DobuleClick
              // there is no event registered and this code could
              // reentered until you exit from func1.
              func1();
         }
    }
    finally
    {
         // Important part. the finally block is required 
         // because you should readd the event handler 
         // ALSO in case an exception occurs in func1 
         // and it is not handled there
         if(c != null) c.DoubleClick += listView_DoubleClick;
    }
}
```

Of course, this is just to enable/disable DoubleClicks events, it cannot works if you assign this event handler to other standard events like Click that have the same signature `(object sender, EventArgs e)`

Comment: This really looks nice. But I cant disable the handler. It gets fired up anyway. I just changed the listView-name in your code and inserted it into mine. No error raised. It just runs through it again.

Comment: I like this solution, but it should be mentioned that it is not thread-safe. This shouldn't be a problem fo "UI event", but if that pattern is used somewhere else it could matter...

Comment: @C4ud3x look at the code in the form.designer.cs InitializeComponent method. You will find how the Visual Studio IDE links your event handler code to the event DoubleClick of the ListView in question. The process is the same.

Comment: Do you have the same event handler assigned to more than one listview?. The disabling -= affects only the listview on the left of the -=, not all the listview that are linked to the same event handler

Comment: Nope. It is only this one listView and also only this one handler.

Comment: Try to use the updated code with the generic Control.

Comment: Hah. I really thought "this is it!". But sorry, it is still fired up.

Comment: Please do a full search of your code (CTRL+SHIFT+F) for listView_DoubleClick and verify if there are some duplicates somewhere.

Comment: I searched through the hole project. There are only this 4 places: designer.cs, the event and our try-finally inside the event. Nothing more.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/63480/discussion-between-steve-and-c4ud3x).

Comment: Was my mistake. This answer solved the question from the first version. The problem is: my question was wrong hah.

Answer (score 1):

How about something like the following using locks:

```
private object globalLock = new object();
private Dictionary<int, object> lockObjects = new Dictionary<int, object>();

public void listView_DoubleClick(object sender, EventArgs e) 
{
    object lockObject;
    lock (globalLock) // to avoid two threads creating the object
    {
        if (!lockObjects.ContainsKey(1))
            lockObjects.Add(1, new object());
        lockObject = lockObjects[1];
    }

    if (Monitor.TryEnter(lockObject) // enter only if no thread has already entered
    {
        try { func1(); }
        finally { Monitor.Exit(lockObject); }
    }
}
```

This is different to Steve's logic in the matter that it is thread-safe.

Comment: Thanks for you post. My question wasnt clear enough at this point. I need it to be ignored instead of enqueued.

Comment: @C4ud3x: I updated my answer with a thread-safe alternative to Steves. If you do not need thread-safety use his solution...

Answer (score 0):

A simple state-machine should solve your problem without requiring too many variables. Create an `Enum` named AppState like this:

```
enum AppState
{
     Ready = 1,
     InsideListView1Click = 2,
     InsideListView1DoubleClick = 3
     InsideListView2Click = 4,
     InsideListView2DoubleClick = 5
}
```

This enum could grow as you add new controls and/or event-handlers to your application. Now use a single global variable that keeps track of the application state and modify it inside event-handlers appropriately:

```
private AppState m_State = AppState.Ready;
```

And in the event-handlers you would do:

```
private void ListView1_DoubleClick(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    lock
    {
        if(m_State != AppState.Ready)
            return;
        else
            m_State = AppState.InsideListView1DoubleClick;
    }

    //Do your stuff

    m_State = AppState.Ready;
 }
```

This way newer calls will be ignored instead of being queued. If you expect to be in multiple states at the same time, you could apply `[Flags]` attribute on this enum as well. Also note that enums are thread-safe and evaluating them is atomic, so multi-threading shouldn't be a problem either.

Comment: I got about 20 events for now that need to be handled this way. When using your Enum-Solution I would also need to write down all the events inside. Would be the same amout of code as declaring global bool variables. Im looking for a 'less-code'-solution, thanks anyway.